# Nginx authentication and redirect to https

Tags: nginx

I'm having an hard time trying to add some security to a site,
Basically I wish that what's under a directory must:

```
1) be redirected to https if http
2) be under HttpAuthBasicModule
```

for some reasons I can get the auth to work, but it's not redirecting to https for certain urls, such as /index.php, but it does for some other files:

```
/revive/www/admin/assets/images/login-welcome.gif works
/revive/www/admin/index.php remains under port 80
```

this is the relevant part of my nginx config file

```
location ^~ /revive/www/admin  {

    if ($server_port = 80) {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
    }

    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  htpasswd_revive;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=revive.host.com";
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

How could I make sure that everything under /revive/www/admin is redirected to port 443 if  it's called on port 80? any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

turns out it seems to be working if I do this:

```
location ^~ /revive/www/admin  {

    if ($server_port = 80) {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
    }

    auth_basic            "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file  htpasswd_revive;

    location ~ \.php$ {

        if ($server_port = 80) {
            rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
        }

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "newrelic.appname=revive.host.com";
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless there is no other options using `if` with nginx is strongly recommended against: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil People seeing this now should use the approach by Lury above.

Answer (score 1):

put your server rules only with "listen 443" and add the following rule bellow:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysite.com;
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: unluckily i can't do this because i want to redirect to https only that special url, the rest of the site is proxied by varnish

Comment: I don't see any reason why this can't be done, you're already doing it but in a worse method, using `if`